Why have my rim brakes started making a scraping noise?
I bought a bike about 7 months ago, and I've noticed over the last few weeks that it's started making an unpleasant scraping noise when I brake. Does anyone know what might be causing this and how to fix it please?
There's no noise when cycling normally, just when braking, and it becomes louder when braking more sharply or at higher speeds. The noise seems to be only coming from the front brakes.
I first tried removing and cleaning the brake pads and cleaning the rims, neither of which did anything to stop the noise. I then swapped the brake pads out for a brand new set. That didn't help either - if anything, swapping the pads out made it louder.
The bike is a Cannondale Quick 6; according to Cannondale's website the wheel specs are:

Front hub: Shimano, Alloy, Sealed, QR
Rear hub: Shimano, Alloy, Sealed, QR
Rims: Cannondale Disc, double wall w/eyelet, 32h
Spokes: Stainless Steel, 14g
Tyre size: 35
Wheel size : 700c

The brakes are rim brakes. I can't see anything on the website naming the original brake pads, but the pads themselves say 'Promax 260 for alloy' on them. The new pads are Shimano M70T3.
If the noise is harmless I can live with it, but I'm worried that it might be a sign of something causing my bike damage - it certainly doesn't sound healthy. I've recorded a video of the noise here.
Any advice for this worried newbie would be much appreciated. Thanks, and have a nice day!

Can you drop out the front wheel and have a close look at the brake pads?  You're looking for both wear, and embedded metal in the pad.   Also, lightly run your finger around the wheel's brake track feeling for lumps.  Does the rim have a wobble sideways when spun ?

If after checking all of the above from Criggie's comment, you can't find the cause of it, I would take it to a bike shop, if possible to shop where the bike was bought.  It does sound a bit  unusual for a wheel that's only seven months old.  This video talks about brake noise, not just squealing, as the title suggest.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BH9L_w3K5ocThere can be contaminants that has become imbedded in the brake pads but you have new ones so it's unusual... I think.
